# how to avoid or handle stack overflow exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, stack, overflow

how could i avoid or handle stack overflow exception in this code?
(C# language)

```
    public void expand(int i, int j)
    {
        int dan = danger(i, j);
        if (dan == 0)
        {
            button_show(i, j, "");
            if (i != 0)
                expand(i - 1, j);
            if (i != 7)
                expand(i + 1, j);
            if (j != 0)
                expand(i, j - 1);
            if (j != 7)
                expand(i, j + 1);
        }
        else if (dan > 0 && dan < 9)
        {
            button_show(i, j, dan.ToString());
        }


    }
```

exception occurs in this method

```
    public void button_show(int i, int j, string danger)
    {
            this.Controls["b" + i + "n" + j].Text = danger;//this line throw an stack overflow exception
            this.Controls["b" + i + "n" + j].Enabled = false;
    }
```

Danger method is like this

```
public int danger(int i, int j)
    {
        //Check if button is mine
        if (first.mines[i][j] == true)
            //9 is mine
            return 9;
        else
        {
            //d measures danger
            int d = 0;
            if (i != 0 && j != 0)
            {
                if (first.mines[i - 1][j - 1] == true) //top-left
                    d++;
            }
            if (j != 0)
            {
                if (first.mines[i][j - 1] == true) //top
                    d++;
            }
            if (i != 7 && j != 0)
            {
                if (first.mines[i + 1][j - 1] == true) //top-right
                    d++;
            }
            if (i != 0)
            {
                if (first.mines[i - 1][j] == true) //left
                    d++;
            }
            if (i != 7)
            {
                if (first.mines[i + 1][j] == true) //right
                    d++;
            }
            if (i != 0 && j != 7)
            {
                if (first.mines[i - 1][j + 1] == true) //bottom-left
                    d++;
            }
            if (j != 7)
            {
                if (first.mines[i][j + 1] == true) //bottom
                    d++;
            }
            if (i != 7 && j != 7)
            {
                if (first.mines[i + 1][j + 1] == true) //bottom-right
                    d++;
            }
            return d;

        }
    }
```

this method calls the expand method for first time

```
    public void check(int i, int j)
    {
        int dan = danger(i, j);
        if (dan == 9)
            mine();
        else if (dan > 0 && dan < 9)
            button_show(i, j, dan.ToString());
        else if (dan == 0)
            expand(i, j);
    }
```

Visual studio showed this text about exception and no more detail is available

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: Please, show full exception stack

Comment: What is your `danger` method like?

Comment: You need an exit condition. In your current implementation, you call `expand` from `button_show` and whether `dan==0` or not, you immediatelt call `button_show`, which calss `expand` again, (repeat ad infinitum). Somewhere you need to make sure that that loop is broken

Comment: but when danger is not 0 the loop must to be brake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using recursion, recursion needs an end condition to stop the recursion. If not you will trigger a stackoverflow exception. Check your end condition on if it is valid in the case you are testing. You can handle all reclusive functions in a non recursive function, however I guess that you are just missing the end/exit condition.

You have to take into account the places you already know. At this moment you are rechecking them over and over again.

Comment: but in expand method when 'dan' variable is not zero the recursion has to be stop

Comment: yeah if two 0 fields be next to each other first field checks second field and second field checks first field and it will repeat over and over again